# how to add mit-scheme for sicp in linux

Tags: mit-scheme

I am studying Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP).I want to know which mit-scheme is used for this course.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

follow this link:
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mit-scheme/stable.pkg/9.2/mit-scheme-9.2-x86-64.tar.gz
http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Unix-Installation.html
It is helpful to solve your problem